# Authentication token causes DBConcurrencyException

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I'm building REST web API with .Net framework and entity framework. We are using OAuth 2.0 authorization and all request must have valid access token in order to consume API.

I'm having rather unexpected behavior with my services. Business service is doing something like this:

`Create the entity 
 add it to the db
 generate the system comment that entity was created
 add the comment to the`

```
public void Task<MyEntity> Create(entity){

        _entityRepository.Add(entity);

        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        await _entityCommentBusinessService.AddSystemComment(entity, EntitySystemCommentTypes.StatusChangedNewEntity).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await _bookingArtifactService.SetValidity(entity.Id).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return entity;
```

Add system comment generates the comment model and calls AddComment:

```
    public async Task<CommentModel> AddComment(CommentModel model)
    {
        var entity = repository.Create();
        repository.Add(entity);

        MapModelToEntity(model, entity);

        entity.UserId = identity.UserId;
        await context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        return MapEntityToModel(entity);
    }
```

When execution point reaches `SaveChangesAsync()` inside of `AddComment` method an exception is thrown.

When I use one instance of access token ( which is not expired just to be clear) I get `Data exception`.
However this problem does not occur if I take a different token (which again to be clear is not expired) and operation completes successfully.

Also, if i do take unauthorized access token I get Unauthorized 401 which is expected behavior.

I've tried wrapping these actions into a TransactionScope but the problem still persists. 
Since comment must reference entity by ID there's no way of getting around saving changes two times.

Now I know that dbContext is not managed the best way possible but given the circumstances it's too expensive to refactor that at the moment. I could just issue new access tokens for my website that is consuming this API but I don't think that solution is going to work long term.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with token generation. We've issued couple of tokens for each environment that don't expire ( they do but in about a year) so we don't have to worry about that during the development. However, tokens issued from one environment did work on other environments but that didn't mean that user exists in the database. Since comments table is basically the only place for now where I extract `UserId` from `Identity` and save it to the database an exception was thrown because non existing foreign key was referenced.

Takeaways:

- Be careful how you issue your access tokens
- Pray for more descriptive exceptions